# How to create a local Wikidata query service?

Tags: sparql, rdf, dump, wikidata

I'm trying to run a SPARQL query on Wikidata, but it times out. I'd like to download a [dump](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download) and index it in some database, so I can run local SPARQL queries using HTTP requests. I also need to support Wikidata-specific extensions like `SERVICE wikibase:label`. I've downloaded an RDF dump. What are the next steps?

Comment: If you want to use SPARQL, why did your download the JSON dump? SPARQL is an RDF query language. So what does this mean? Exactly, download the RDF dump and load it into a triple store.

Comment: And this is not the right place to ask for tools, you should know this for sure.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks, I'll download the RDF dump. I'll also edit the question, so it won't be a tool recommendation. I don't think any triple store will work, because I need to support wikidata-specific extensions like `SERVICE wikibase:label`, no?

Comment: @dimid the Wikidata extensions indeed won't be available in another triplestore product (isn't it fun when someone decides to extend a standard?) but FWIW for most of those features alternatives are available that _are_ SPARQL-standard-compliant.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thsnks, do you know perhaps which triple store is used by wikidata itself? Hopefully, it'll support the extensions out of the box.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they use Blazegraph - but I think the extensions are Wikidata-specific, and not available in the "normal" Blazegraph distro. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikimedia [has documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Standalone_service) on how to run your own SPARQL endpoint from one of their dumps. They also have an updater  that streams updates from their servers, to keep your endpoint up-to-date.

You won't need to do anything special to support their extensions, it is included by default.

I recommend using a reverse proxy (like nginx or apache) with http auth in production, the admin dashboard is accessible by default.

Comment: Thanks! How can I increase the query timeout to more than 60 seconds, I tried looking in `RWStore.properties`, but haven't found such a setting. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @dimid did you figure out how extend the timeout period?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [qEndpoint](https://github.com/the-qa-company/qEndpoint). There are two options:

1. if you want to set up the endpoint as fast as possible you can use this docker image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/qacompany/qendpoint-wikidata

this will basically install qEndpoint and download the index for whole wikidata. With a good internet connection you should have it in 3 hours.

2. You can index the latest dump by yourself. Here are some instructions:

https://github.com/the-qa-company/qEndpoint/wiki/Use-qEndpoint-to-index-a-dataset#start-the-endpoint

PS: SPARQL 1.1 is supported and also the `SERVICE wikibase:label` clause.